# I'd like to run Termux as root: possible?

Tags: root-access, terminal, termux

I'd like to have an SSH, HTTP and SMB server on standard ports on my phone.

There's a way to run Termux as root and have the servers run on privileged ports?

Running rooted Android 7.1 on an unlocked device.

Answer (score 18):

The default `su` from Termux is simple. When run it brings `/system/bin/sh` for you instead of Termux's shell (typically `bash`). To solve this issue, you can install the custom su wrapper for Termux by

```
apt install tsu
```

And then you can run `tsu` so that your `bash` and everything is now under root privilege.

Further information:
Use an editor (like `vim`) to see `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/su` and you'll find that at line 10, it calls `exec su $@` directly while in `tsu`, it performs shell detection and at line 80, it runs

```
exec su --preserve-environment -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib $ROOT_SHELL"
```

to preserve the Termux enviroment.

Answer (score 6):

I just solved the same problem for myself. tsu didn't work out for me.
I found this project:
https://github.com/st42/termux-sudo

Also I wanted to run sshd as root. It an out of the box with termux-sudo but it didn't want to use the authorized_keys file at first, because the permissions to it and all it's parent directories where not restricted to root (and on my device the / directory cannot be restricted to root 700, because then the mediaplayer software doesn't work anymore for some reason).

So I had to add the option `StrictModes no` to the sshd config file: `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and now it works! :)

Comment: this helped, and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Once you run su it takes you out of the termux subshell. You can try SELinux permissive, that's how I get around the permission denied thing.

Comment: so like i type su, then superuser asks me for root permission, i give it, and then I have to run the servers as root? Or once i did that i can run servers with normal user but they still can get privileged ports?