# Termux/node.js steam hourboost on android

Tags: applications, scripts

i'm newbie in scripting i'm trying to run node.js script with termux on android and i'm getting errors everytime i have no idea how to fix i know nothing about that so what code must i use?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuRMn.jpg here is screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKW0.jpg he do it without problems

Answer (score 1):

From the console it seems, the script requires root privileges to be executed which are not available/disabled on your device

Comment: Hey, thank u so much for response, i have rooted device but still not working

Comment: Have you checked the logs, and see the information there?

Comment: Which logs? i checked termux logs but here is ony npm-debug

Comment: Btw i have rooted phone but still i can't find termux's default directory ''/data/data/com.termux/files/home.'' i change it to /storage/emulated/0/Download/Termux i rooted device with KingRoot

Comment: I think your device was not properly rooted.  How recent did you perfom the rooting?

Comment: I used KingRoot for root

Comment: Did you try using [tsu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167177/273059)? But yeah, sounds like you're not really rooted.