# How do I view root ( / ) with Termux if termux-setup-storage doesn't help?

Tags: internal-storage, stock-android, termux

After reviewing [this](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Internal_and_external_storage), I used `termux-setup-storage` on my phone and Andy Android emulator.

After running the above command, I am able to view root directory with `ls`
on Andy emulator but not on phone.

**INFO:**
Android version 7.1.1
Xperia XZ
SoftBank locked the phone BIOS (or whatever it was) so I can't root it.
Storage permissions are granted.

What else can I try to use `ls` on root directory on my phone?

Comment: In Linux subject, "root" refers to the root of the file hierarchy `/`, not "root of Android storage" which is usually `/storage/emulated/0`. Which one do you mean?

Comment: root as in /  .  I didn't mention android storage. The script does a number of things like setup android storage but it also gives permission to view root on Andy and I mean the actual root,  so I'm wondering what went wrong on phone

Comment: You may want to provide more information like Android version.

Comment: @chrips Note that `termux-setup-storage` has no effect on `/`. Moreover, I'm able to `ls /` as non-root user, so your situation might very well depend on your phone's configuration of `/`'s permissions, even moreso when Andy lets you see the directory's contents.

Comment: I'll dig around for an answer and close this if I can't find a solution. It's a pretty general question now

Comment: Andy is rooted by default, but real Android devices are not. Termux also does not have root user access by default AFAIK, and if your phone isn't rooted won't be able to access much of the filesystem outside of Termux and the SD card anyways, but [the answers to this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167177) may help in your situation if your physical device is/can be rooted.

Comment: Thanks to all for this bounty of information. I can now answer my own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't root your phone, you can't see root /
The termux-storage-storage allows you to access SD card storage and NOT root /

Note:
Andy emulator IS rooted by default 
- Thanks l3l_aze, iBug, Death Mask Salesman, Irfan Latif

Answer (score 4):

`termux-setup-storage` only grants [android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) that lets the app access internal SD card i.e. `/sdcard`.

Android's init creates rootfs `/` with permissions `0:0` (uid:gid) and `0755` (mode). So the root directory should be accessible to any non-root user.
However SELinux plays its role restricting unauthorized access to rootfs. You can view such policy denials by:

```
dmesg | grep 'avc: denied'
```

<sup>* Most probably SELinux will deny this command too if run from non-root app</sup>

To view all SEPolicy rules, `sesearch` tool from [setools-android](https://github.com/xmikos/setools-android/releases) can be used.

To set SELinux permissive:

```
echo 0 >/sys/fs/selinux/enforce
# or
setenforce 0
```

Or add an exception to SELinux policy:

```
supolicy --live 'allow untrusted_app rootfs dir { read open }'
```

<sup>* `supolicy` tool is provided by rooting solutions e.g. Magisk, SuperSu</sup>

This policy allows reading rootfs but still you may get errors because reading attributes of files/directories under rootfs isn't permitted by policy.

Also both solutions need root privileges and are nonpersistent i.e. need to be set after reboot.

So if you are running a non-rooted production build of Android (with enforcing SELinux), you won't be able to read rootfs `/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.   Also: "dmesg | grep 'avc: denied'"   gives   dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Permission denied      If I cant even use dmesg I think up the creek without a paddle!

Comment: @chrips yeah, your SELinux policy doesn't let the `dmesg` read kernel log, so you get another `avc denial` while trying to read already occured `avc denials`